# SwipeAction not changeing color with .tint() modifier

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios16

```
List{
            Button{
                //Checking in
            }label: {
                Text("Check in")
                    .swipeActions {
                        Button{
                           //Checking in
                        }label: {
                            Text("Check in")
                        }.tint(.red)
                    }
            }
        }
```

I've tried to change the color of the background when swiping on a row. Nothing happens.
It just keeps being the standard gray.

[image]

I've looked at a bunch of other people and it seems like they all put the modifier at the same place as me but they get a different result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `.buttonStyle(.plain)` to the `Button` in the List:

```swift
List {
    Button {
        //Checking in
    } label: {
        Text("Check in")
            .swipeActions {
                Button {
                    //Checking in
                } label: {
                    Text("Check in")
                }
                .tint(.red)
            }
    }
    .buttonStyle(.plain)            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you are trying to set a swipe action on the `Text`, while it's the `Button` that's swiping.

Just apply the modifier on the `Button` instead of the `Text`:

```
List{
    Button{
        //Checking in
    }label: {
        Text("Check in")
    }
    
    // The modifier is applied on the  Button, not on the Text
    .swipeActions {
        Button{
            //Checking in
        }label: {
            Text("Check in")
        }.tint(.red)
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I apply the modifier to the button? I tried to put it before the label but that resulted in an error

Comment: Just look at the answer. The modifier is after both closures (the `label:` is a parameter of the `Button`). Copy the code.